# Element IDs in a document loaded with NSURLConnection come empty?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ios, nsurlconnection

In my web application, I use `NSURLConnection` first to make an asynchronous request downloading the (url document) data to NSData. In my local jQuery I set a cookie based on user interaction (clicked event.target etc), which I would fetch the next time the same request is made.
So the cookie is of the format,

```
  value=event.target.id;
  clickedTarget=value;
```

This works well when used with method

```
    [webView loadRequest:]
```

However, with `NSURLConnection`, the cookie is set with an empty value, and the cookie looks like

```
   clickedTarget=;
```

I don't know what's going wrong with `NSURLConnection`, except a guess that the downloaded NSData does not retain the element IDs.

Am I correct here? Is there a solution to make the `NSData` give the element id correctly?

TIA,

Nikhil

Answer (score 0):

`NSURLConnection` uses its own cookie store, so while your `UIWebView` may have a cookie as defined via jQuery, the rest of your app doesn't.

Here's how you can use the "Shared HTTP Cookie Store" used by `UIWebView` for your custom `NSMutableURLRequest`:

```
NSArray *cookies = [[NSHTTPCookieStorage sharedHTTPCookieStorage] cookiesForURL:someURL];
NSDictionary *cookieHeaders = [NSHTTPCookie requestHeaderFieldsWithCookies:availableCookies];
[request setAllHTTPHeaderFields:cookieHeaders];
```

### Edit

Not sure I understand what you mean. The content of a document received from the server is exactly the same, regardless if it is fetched in a `UIWebView` or your `NSURLConnection`. However, JavaScript scripts will not be executed when downloading via `NSURLConnection`!

Comment: actually my problem is not setting up cookie, but setting the cookie value to an element on the original downloaded page, which works with UIWebView, but seems empty with NSURLConnection. I realized I used an imprecise title for the question, which I am trying to change now.